# changing the value onclick in react-js

Tags: react-native, reactjs

[output look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTMJj.png) when i click change text button it should replace the text (TodoApplication) with that value if it is empty value(should replace empty heading) the value was not changing in this code! can anyone edit the code to get a solution!

```js
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
return {items: []};
  },
  updateItems: function(newItem) {
var allItems = this.state.items.concat([newItem]);
this.setState({items: allItems});
  },
  render: function() {
return (
  <div>
    <TodoBanner/>
    <TodoList items={this.state.items}/>

    <TodoForm onFormSubmit={this.updateItems}/>
  </div>
);
  }
});

var TodoBanner = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
return (
  <div className="container">
    <h3>TODO Application</h3>
  </div>
);
  }
});

var TodoList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
var createItem = function(itemText) {
  return (
    <TodoListItem>{itemText}
    </TodoListItem>
  );
};
return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
  }
});

var TodoListItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
return (
  <li>{this.props.children}</li>
);
  }
});

var TodoForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
return {item: ''};
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.props.onFormSubmit(this.state.item);
this.setState({item: ''});
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.item).focus();
return;
  },
  onChange: function(e) {
this.setState({item: e.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
return (
  <div className="container">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type='text' ref='item' onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.item}/>
      &nbsp;
      <input type='submit' value='Add' className="btn btn-success"/><br/>
      <input type='text' ref='item' onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.item}/>
      &nbsp;
      <input type='submit' value='Change Text' className="btn btn-success"/>
    </form>
  </div>
);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoApp/>, document.getElementById('todo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="todo" />
```

Comment: Please explain your question correctly.

Comment: okay! Actually i want to change the text in todobanner function() with the value of second input box as get from user on click second button in the render function() help me !@RIYAJKHAN

Comment: @gkraj see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I didn't get what you mean. Did you mean something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/alfrcr/upzqf067/1/

If so, in order to change the 'Todo Application' text, you should send the form state to the upper component.

So `TodoBanner` can access 'that form state' as a `props`. (See the example code)